# StackWalk64 and custom unwind data (x64 stack) retrieval

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit, stack-trace, dbghelp

Is it possible to make `StackWalk64` load and use a RUNTIME_FUNCTION table extracted by me?
The only way I found out is loading it using `SymLoadModule64` when it is used, it is very slow.

I also saw that `StackWalk64` can receive a function that will give it the appropriate RUNTIME_FUNCTION entry each time, but it would require me to implement the x64 UNWINDING algorithm which is partly undocumented.

Is it possible to do so using `RtlInstallFunctionTableCallback` or `RtlAddFunctionTable`? Are they related to `StackWalk64`?
And if so, how? I couldn't find examples for this.

Comment: Upvote for this because I couldn't ever figure it out either.  If you want to use DbgEng, and have registered a custom function table callback (via the methods you mentioned), you can use IDebugControl4::GetContextStackTrace to get the full stack.  I had a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653719/how-do-you-walk-a-mixed-mode-managednative-stack-with-dbghelpstackwalk64

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'extracted by me'. Using RtlAddFunctionTable you can add RUNTIME_FUNCTION dynamically, and I think it should be picked up by StackWalk64 (I have not tried).

A sample demonstrating exception handling with RtlAddFunctionTable is at https://pmeerw.net/blog/programming/RtlAddFunctionTable.html.